# How to save a sparse matrix to mat file in matlab

Tags: matlab, sparse-matrix

I want to save two sparse matrix Y and R to a mat file. However, when I run the following code, I found out that the `twomatrices.mat` contains two full matrices instead of sparse matrices. Do does .mat file only allow full matrices to be included?

```
save('twomatrices.mat', 'Y', 'R');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be sure that you actually create sparse matrices: e.g., the following code snippet works fine and stores the matrices as sparse double matrices:

```
n = 5;
Y = sparse(1:n,1:n,1);
R = sparse(1:n,1:n,2);
save('twomatrices.mat', 'Y', 'R');

clear
load('twomatrices.mat')
Y


Y =

   (1,1)        1
   (2,2)        1
   (3,3)        1
   (4,4)        1
   (5,5)        1
```

Comment: +1 Just because a matrix has many zeros in it, does not automatically make it into a sparse form. Use whos to verify the status of those matrices before they are written out.